# how to append a data in a specific DIV in JQUERY

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

im having some trouble with my JQUERY.

basically, i have this facebook style of displaying posts. each posts has `<input>` box where members can leave comments. when a user hits `<enter>` my jquery(AJAX), will fetch the submitted comment and save it on my database.

the comment should appear instantly in the specific `<DIV>` where the comment was made.

my issue is, whenever i submit a comment on a specific **POST** the comment i made gets updated to **ALL** of my posts. it will only disappear when i hit refresh.

this is my `<div>` that displays the **TITLE** and the **COMMENTS**

```
<div id="content">
    <?php 
    /* GET TITLE*/
    $result = displayPosts(); 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $rowId = $row['id'];

    ?>
    /* ECHO TITLE*/     
    <b> <?php echo $row['title'] . "<br />"; ?> </b>

    <?php   
    /* GET COMMENTS PER POSTS */
    $comRes = getComments($rowId);
        while ($comRow = $comRes->fetch_assoc()) { 
    ?>

    <!--COMMENT AREA-->
    <div class="comments">
        <!--DISPLAY COMMENTS-->
        <small> <?php echo $comRow['comment'] . "<br />";?> </small>
    </div>

    <?php } /* end of second while loop */ ?> 

    <input type="text" post_id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="TextBox" name="input" value="" />

    <?php } /* end of first while loop */ ?> 
</div>
```

THIS IS MY JQUERY. Whenever a user hits `<enter>` on a particular POST it should display the comment **on that specific DIV/POSTS only**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#TextBox').keyup(function (z) {
        /* when this commentbox is entered*/
        if(z.keyCode == 13) {   /*keyCode 13 = enter*/ 
                var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');  /* get the post_id in the <input> box */
                var comment = $(this).val(); /* get the value of the <input> */
                $.post('../portal/comment.php', {post_id: post_id, comment: comment});
                $('input#TextBox').val('');
                $(this).parent('#content').children('.comments').append("<div>"+comment+"</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

this line contains my `post_id` so whenever i hit enter in my input box, my system knows what specific post im referring to..

```
<input type="text" post_id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" id="TextBox" name="input" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line :

```
$(this).parent('#content').children('.comments').append("<div>"+comment+"</div>");
```

With this you are appending the new comment text in each `div` with `comments` css class.

You could perform something like :

```
<!-- Add post id to identify corresponding comment area -->
<div class="<?php echo $rowId; ?>_comments comments"> 
    <small> <?php echo $comRow['comment'] . "<br />";?> </small>
</div>
```

Then in your js :

```
$(function() {
    $('input#TextBox').keyup(function (z) {
        if(z.keyCode == 13) {
            var input = $(this);
            var post_id = input.attr('post_id');
            var comment = input.val();
            $.post('../portal/comment.php', {post_id: post_id, comment: comment});
            $('input#TextBox').val('');
            // Append comment to the corresponding div
            $('.' + post_id + '_comments').append("<div>"+comment+"</div>");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way that you are trying to distinguish your comment DIVs. Suppose you want to choose a special comment div. How can you do this in your webpage?
Using this code will not give you a *special* comment div:

```
$(".comments")
```

You should give each comment DIV a special identity (which is simply an html `id`). This way you can select it easily, for example:

```
$("#comments_14")
```

and updating would become a little more complex. Instead of the following line:

```
$(this).parent('#content').children('.comments').append("<div>"+comment+"</div>");
```

you should do something like this:

```
var post_id = get post id some way; // e.g. put it in an attribute in text input
$('#comments_' + post_id).append("<div>"+comment+"</div>");
```